# How to collect all the rows with a specific date from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Here I have a dataframe named **all_data**. It has a column named **'Order Date'**, which is of the format datetime. I want to create a new dataframe named **'aug4'**, which contains all the rows from the **'all_data'** dataframe having the date August 4 (year is 2019 for all entries). How do I go about doing the same?

[image: This is what all_data.head() outputs.]

I tried doing

```
aug4 = all_data.loc[all_data['Order Date'].year == 2019 & all_data['Order Date'].month == 8 & all_data['Order Date'].day == 4]
```

But it does not work.

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `Date` from `DateTime` and check with `Date` like below:

```
>>> all_data[all_data['Order Date'].dt.date == pd.to_datetime('2019-08-29')]
```

OR you can convert `DateTime` to `str` and check with `Date` as str:

```
>>> all_data[all_data['Order Date'].dt.date.astype(str) == '2019-08-29']
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert date column to datetime:

```
all_data['Order Date'] = pd.to_datetime(all_data['Order Date'])
```

Then wrap your conditions inside () brackets and get year, month and day using **dt** accessor:

```
aug4 = all_data.loc[(all_data['Order Date'].dt.year == 2019) & (all_data['Order Date'].dt.month == 8) & (all_data['Order Date'].dt.day == 4)]
```

Comment: I have already converted it to datetime().

Comment: Then just use the brackets with conditions and dt accessor to access year, month and day in your code.